# regex to find anchor tag which have not closing tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the below regex to find anchor tag which have not closing tag but it is not working.
Only match which does not have closing tag.
can any provide the correct regex which would really works in this condition.

Regex :

```
<a[^><]+\b(?!>)
```

(It also selects the anchor tag which have closing tag)

https://regex101.com/r/LbmI2G/1

[image]

Comment: can u provide an example of a desirable output with example inputs? and also do not post images, copy and paste the code so people can reproduce it.

Comment: I want to match only below string also I have provided link above.

<a href="http://www.example.com/2015/05/choco-taco.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more simplistic than Tim's but here's a basic idea:

1. Match on a `<` before a `>`, or:
2. Match on no following `>`

[`<a[^><]+((?=<)|(?!.*>))`](https://regex101.com/r/LbmI2G/3)

[image]

Comment: In substitution it breaks the last div of 1.

1. cipe at /div>

Comment: @AMitSiNgh hm? Add `?:` to the group to make it a non-grouping class

Comment: `<a[^><]+((?=<)|(?!.*>))` ?

Comment: Can you please explaint this part. 
(?!.*>) why we put .* here

Comment: @AMitSiNgh `.*` would mean one of more of anything -- `.` (dot) matches all. So doing `(?!<something>)` is a negative lookahead to make sure that `<something>` does not occur at the position after the current cursor location, and putting the `.*` before the <something> makes sure that `<something>` never occurs at all. Note that `.` in the above case does not include newline (but it can depending on the regex settings).